# Serializing a Map with custom MapAdapter in moshi

Tags: serialization, kotlin, android-json, jsonserializer, moshi

I am trying to write a custom `MapAdapter` in [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi/) My requirement is to ignore any bad elements in the map. I have successfully written deserialization method(`fromJson()`), however, I am facing trouble with `toJson`. here is my `toJson()` method.

```
override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Map<Any?, Any?>?) {
            if (value == null) {
                writer.nullValue()
            } else {
                writer.beginObject()
                value.forEach {
                    writer.name(elementKeyAdapter.toJsonValue(it.key).toString())
                        .value(elementValueAdapter.toJson(it.value))
                }
                writer.endObject()
            }
        }
```

problem with this code is that it always is writing values in map as string in final Json. For example consider this code

```
enum class VehicleType2 {
    @Json(name ="type1")
    TYPE1,

    @Json(name ="type2")
    TYPE2,

    @Json(name ="type3")
    TYPE3,

    @Json(name ="type4")
    TYPE4,
}
```

and

```
        val map = mutableMapOf<VehicleType2, Int>()
        map[VehicleType2.TYPE1] = 1
        map[VehicleType2.TYPE2] = 2
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<Map<VehicleType2, Int>> =
            moshi.adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, VehicleType2::class.java, Integer::class.java))
        Log.i("test", adapter.toJson(map))
```

this results in following Json

```
{"type1":"1","type2":"2"}
```

notice how `1` and `2` are `strings` and not `integers`. I have tried many permutations bit no success so far.

Here is [more complete sample](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/MoshiTest/tree/bad_elements_map_adapter) which reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After few more trials and errors I found that this is working fine

```
                    writer.name(elementKeyAdapter.toJsonValue(it.key).toString())
                    elementValueAdapter.toJson(writer, it.value)
```

instead of

```
writer.name(elementKeyAdapter.toJsonValue(it.key).toString())
                        .value(elementValueAdapter.toJson(it.value))
```

I am still unsure about the reasoning behind it though. Thanks!